# Metalanguage to describe expressing an idea in many different ways

Tags: semantics, phrase-requests

I am looking for a term to describe expressing an idea in many different forms yet the meaning remains the same in each rendition.

An example of this:

*The Australians, Australians, the Australian people, the people of Australia, Australia's people etc.*

All the phrases above virtually express the same thing yet they are all different, lexico-grammatically speaking.

Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The word *[synonym](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synonym)* probably describes what you're saying.

Comment: I did think about synonymy but a rigorous definition of synonyms requires them to be part of the same word class. The examples I have given do not adhere to this rule. Perhaps I could coin a new bit of metalanguage: _synonymophrasis_

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the term or idiomatic expression you are looking for is: "There are many ways to kill a cat."

This idiom means there is more than one method to achieve a certain end or that there are many ways to express a particular thought.